# Headers in iPad are doubled

Tags: html, css, ipad, mobile-safari

I'm noticing headers output by the iPad in Safari are doubling up. Not just on 1 site but seemingly all of them that I have built. Attached is one of the sites, and you can see it in the large h1 heading in the background and the h2 heading go the blog post. The title of the blog post you can actually see the type split.

Why is this occurring?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It appears you've forgotten to attach the site's URL.

Comment: A question from this post can be implied but it isn't stated.  So, for clarity sake, what are you asking?

Comment: I added the actual question of what is causing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the h1 tag is bold, and you haven't provided a bold version of your webfont, Safari is using a technique of it's own to make the text appear bold. It's artificial text emboldening.

If you set the font-weight to normal, the text will no longer double.

Comment: I zoomed in quite close, and this does not happen on the desktop. I'll post an image shortly.

Comment: Try setting the font-weight as normal and you'll see the text no longer doubles

Comment: This would be the answer. Maybe mod or clarify your answer above.